# IF Function with different values returned based on multiple conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement

I want to use a formula that lets me to do the following in excel.

If A2="7M" then return FED
If A2 = "61" then return EC
or else none of those then return DTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need a nested if statement `=if(A2="7M","FED",if(A2=61,"EC","DTC"))`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
=IF(A2="7M","FED",IF(A2="61","EC","DTC"))
```

This assumes that you are looking for a text 61 rather than a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(A2="7M","FED",IF(OR(A2="61",A2=61),"EC","DTC"))
```

The `OR()` will catch both `61` as a number or text.

Or, if you want to add more conditions, use a VLOOKUP():

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$D$10,2,FALSE),"DTC")
```

with `C2:D10`:

[image]

So if you want, say, `3M` to return `FNKY`, just put `3M` in `C4`, and `FNKY` in `D4`.